# How to use navigation in App.js or index.js of react-native?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, navigation

I'm developing an app using react-native and AWS.

I want to navigate to another screen using data of Push Notification.
I receive push notifications and data at App.js(foreground) and index.js(background).
(Data is correct.)
But I don't know how to use navigation object in App.js and index.js.

If I use navigation like below,

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

I got below error

```
ERROR  Error: Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?
```

Any advice will be greatly helpful. Even small suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

Below are my source.

---

### index.js

```
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
Notifications.Push.enable();

const myAsyncNotificationReceivedHandler = async notification => {
  ***// I want to use navigation in this line (ex> navigation.navigate(notification.data.screen);)***
};

Notifications.Push.onNotificationReceivedInBackground(
  myAsyncNotificationReceivedHandler,
);
```

---

### App.js

```
useEffect(() => {
    handlePermissions();
    const listener = Notifications.Push.onTokenReceived(myTokenReceivedHandler);
    Notifications.Push.onNotificationReceivedInForeground(async message => {
      if (message.body) {
        Alert.alert(message.title, message.body);
      }
      **// I want to use navigation in this line (ex> navigation.navigate(message.data.screen);)**
    });
    return () => listener && listener.remove();
  }, []);

return (
    <AuthContextProvider deviceToken={deviceToken}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <CommonContextProvider>
              <RootNavigator />
            </CommonContextProvider>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  );
```

Comment: Check https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/